# Reading n numbers and counting +ve, -ve numbers and zeroes in the list in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd start with saying that I'm new with Javascript.
About the question, I'm very confident that I can do the latter part, but I'm having issues with "reading n numbers".
This is what I've tried

```js
var arr = [];
arr.push(prompt("Enter numbers.").split(","));

function Fun() {
  var countPos = 0;
  var countZer = 0;
  var countNeg = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      countPos++;
    } else if (arr[i] === 0) {
      countZer++
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      countNeg++
    }
  }
  document.write(countPos + " " + countZer + " " + countNeg);
}
Fun();
```

And I'm getting

> 0 0 0

as result no matter how many numbers I put in separated by a comma.
I also tried

```js
var arr = [];

function Fun() {
  arr.push(form1.num.value);
  var countPos = 0;
  var countZer = 0;
  var countNeg = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      countPos++;
    } else if (arr[i] === 0) {
      countZer++
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      countNeg++
    }
  }
  document.write(countPos + " " + countZer + " " + countNeg);
}
```

and I get the same result. This is the accompanying html to he second code btw

```
<body>
  <form name="form1">
   Enter numbers separated by comma: <input type="text" name="num">
   <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="Fun()">
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm assuming I'm not reading the numbers the right way. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Arrray.split function creates an array in it of itself, thus there is no need for the preceeding Array.push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the splitted values,

```
var arr = prompt("Enter numbers.").split(",");
```

because you pushed only a single item (an array of values) to the array. This led to a check of the array and every condition is `false`.

Then you need to check with zero only by a non strict equation, because you get after splitting a string `'0'` and this is never strict equal to `0` ([Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)).

```
} else if (arr[i] == 0) {
//                ^^
```

```js
var arr = prompt("Enter numbers.").split(",");

function Fun() {
  var countPos = 0;
  var countZer = 0;
  var countNeg = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
      countPos++;
    } else if (arr[i] == 0) {
      countZer++
    } else if (arr[i] < 0) {
      countNeg++
    }
  }
  console.log(countPos + " " + countZer + " " + countNeg);
}

Fun();
```

Comment: Wow that worked. Thanks! For the second code, I replaced ```arr.push(form1.num.value);``` with ```arr = form1.num.value;``` too and it's counting negative numbers as positive. No idea what's the issue with that.

Comment: please add the value of `form1.num.value`.

Answer (score 0):

This guy will work for what you want

https://jsfiddle.net/do3r0cmb/2/

```
<script>
function Fun(){
  let numbers = form1.num.value;
  if (numbers.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
numbers = numbers.split(',');
  } else {
    numbers = numbers.split(' ');
  }

  var countPos=0;
  var countZer=0;
  var countNeg=0;
  for(let i in numbers){
    if(numbers[i] > 0){
      countPos++;
    }
else if(numbers[i] < 0){
      countNeg++
    } else {
      countZer++
    }
  }
  console.log(countPos + " " + countZer + " " + countNeg);
}</script>
<body>
  <form name="form1">
   Enter numbers separated by comma: <input type="text" name="num">
   <input type="button" value="Done" onclick="Fun()">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't understand what's happening here since I don't know that much Javascript. I'll surely try it once I know what all that means. Thanks!